# How to display column number in jmesa?

Tags: java, web, jmesa

I want to display current column no in the jmesa , like 1 2 3 4... 
how can I implement that?

Comment: Do you mean current *row* number for each row?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has bennd solved. Override the method render(Object item,int rowcount) of HtmlCellRender to return rowcount.